# Fullcalendar onEventClick is showing wrong date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar object in my application. I'm updating calendar events dynamically to the calendar and they are rendering it perfectly. But, when I click on the event in callback function it's showing the date & time by adding local time zone even though it is already done.

Below is the image of calendar event & on-click event function callback outputs.

here is the sample code

**HTML**

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var  onEventClick = function (calEvent,jsEvent,view){
    console.log(calEvent);
}

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: true,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                end: moment("2017-08-04T23:30:00.000Z"),
                start: moment("2017-08-04T22:30:00.000Z"),
      dow:[1,3,5]
            }
        ],
   eventClick: onEventClick,
    });

});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/bpb95e5x/1/)

Can any one point out what went wrong here

Comment: Please post your code instead of screenshots.

Comment: Added the sample code. In console log it adding local timezone even it is already added.

Comment: @Salesman , check the answer , and let me know , this solution is helpful to you or not?

Comment: @chiragsatapara Thanks man, It is solved but why do we need to take extra 2 parameters for this ?

Comment: @Salesman , becuase full calander always convert start and end date based on your computer timezone, that's why you need to add two extra parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/bpb95e5x/2/).

I just add two values in event , one is `start_date` and another is `end_date` , check this two objects in console. now your new code is :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    
  var  onEventClick = function (calEvent,jsEvent,view){
     console.log(calEvent);
    }
    
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },
   defaultDate: new Date(),
   defaultView: 'month',
   editable: true,
   events: [
    {
     title: 'Long Event',
     end: moment("2017-08-04T23:30:00.000Z"),
     start: moment("2017-08-04T22:30:00.000Z"),
          start_date:moment("2017-08-04T22:30:00.000Z"),
          end_date:moment("2017-08-04T23:30:00.000Z"),
          dow:[1,3,5]
    }
   ],
        eventClick: onEventClick,
  });
    
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>





<div id='calendar'></div>
```

you will find original dates inside `start_date` and `end_date` objects.

Hope this answer will helpfull to you.

Comment: Thanks Problem Solved. But why we need to take start_date,end_date ? can't we achieve this with start,end params only ?